# Find unique/distinct files in windows powershell.

Tags: sorting, powershell, unique, distinct

Being absolutely new to PowerShell, I was wondering what the direct script would be to find all the distinct names of files that have the string "E xx"in them.

In my case in this file folder I have, there are 2000+ pdf files with various names, such as E 52 (40 files containing this string), E 44 (12 files containing this string), E 56 (one file containing this string) etc. The number of different strings are random, but every single one of the 2000+ files contains the letter E and have a space after it. I am hoping to use that as a search indicator. The number of files for each string is also random.

I need to sort the files into folders, and I would like to quickly find the strings in this folder so I can quickly create the folders and sort them.

After doing some research, I learned that you must use the "unique" cmd after the lines of text. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
cd c:\Folder
ls | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.BaseName -cmatch 'E\s\d{2}' } | % { 
   $folder = $matches[0]
   new-item -ItemType Directory -Path . -Name $folder -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
   move-item $_.Name $folder
}
```

Idk if this helps, but I suggest more research.

If you were talking about just doing

`ls | ? {$_.Name -cmatch "E\s\d{2}"} | select unique`

That might not be very useful

Comment: The filter could be simplified to `? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.BaseName -cmatch 'E \d{2}' }`.

Comment: Thanks, updated to make it cleaner, wasn't aware of cmatch, i like.

Comment: Please don't use `\s` when the requirement is to match a space. `\s` matches more than just spaces.

Comment: And considering there is no quantifier next to the \s the white space will always be just one space... It is better practice than just leaving a blank

Comment: Wrong. Whitespace is not just spaces. It also includs tabs, linefeeds, carriage returns and formfeeds.

Comment: The modern regex engine that powershell uses is always going to return 1 whitespace when you use \s without a quantifier.. prove me wrong.

Comment: so can I literally copy that (change the "folder" file path obviously) into PowerShell? Sorry, I am completely new to this and I have trouble reading it.

Comment: Yes Powershell ISE, change file path, let her rip

Comment: @Cole9350 `"\`t" -match '\s'`. Now, that was easy.

Comment: Just because NTFS doesn't allow tabs in file names doesn't mean should get sloppy about your regular expressions.

Comment: It's a difference of opinion. You don't have to come in and tell me how to "simplify" my code when it works just the same. The "Requirement" was to match a space in a file name. My code will always do that in every scenario without error... PowerShell Troll.